# Import Data Into Hive Containing Whitespace

Tags: hive

I am importing data from a csv file into Hive. My table contains both strings and ints. However, in my input file, the ints have whitespace around them, so it kind of looks like this:

```
some string,     2    ,another string  ,    7    , yet another string
```

Unfortunately I cannot control the formatting of the program providing the file.

When I import the data using (e.g.):

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE(string1 STRING, alpha INT, string2 STRING, beta INT, string3 STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Then all my integers get set to NULL. I am assuming this is because the extra whitespace makes the parsing fail. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a multi-stage import. In the first stage, save all of your data as `STRING` and in the second stage use `trim()` to remove whitespace and then save the data as `INT`. You could also look into using Pig to read the data from your source files as raw text and then write it to Hive as with the correct data types.

**Edit**

You can also do this in one pass if you can point to your source file as an external table.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(
    string1 STRING, alpha STRING, string2 STRING, beta STRING, string3 STRING
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '\\server\path\file.csv'

INSERT INTO myOtherTable
SELECT string1,
       CAST(TRIM(alpha) AS INT),
       string2,
       CAST(TRIM(beta) AS INT),
       string3
FROM myTable;
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll mark as correct unless anyone knows of a way of doing it in one pass.

Comment: If you can connect to your source data as an external table you can also process this in one pass. I'll edit my answer appropriately.

Comment: I'm still having problems with this approach because, if you change the data type to `double` the whitespaces are ignored...

Comment: What exactly are you asking/saying, @grundprinzip? Are you saying that using a `double` won't import '   2 ' as a number? Knowing which version of Hive/Hadoop you're on will help someone answer your question (which you should post as a new question) better.

Comment: Actually double will import " 2  " as 2.0 into the table but it won't import " 2  " as 2 (stores NULL instead) into the table. I'm on CDH5. Currently I follow your approach, but it just feels bad.